# getValueAt Method of AbstractTableModel Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I need some help with getValue method

Im reading from a file and storing the values in a

```
 public List<Object[]> students;
```

Now I want to add all of this values to my JTable

```
 @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        //return data[row][col];
        // Here I have to get data from students
    }
```

Usually from a lot of example I saw that they use `Object[][] data` for doing this kind of thing
this could be something like this

```
//return data[row][col];
```

but since I read from a file I want `List<Object[]> students;`

Any Idea how to implement this in getValueAt method?

my solution will be this

```
@Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        //return data[row][col];
        for(Object[] j: students)
        {
            return j[col];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

but this will only take the first object and will assign to all rows in my JTable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

how about:

```
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    return students.get(row)[col];
}
```

Comment: bingo ))) 

Wow I tried the .get(), but never thought that I could put .get()[] 

thank you man!!!
I will mark it as answer in 8 minutes

Comment: @Nicholas: It's a simple shortcut for `Object[] student = students.get(row); return student[col];` But everything would be much cleaner and simpler if students was a `List<Student>` rather than a `List<Object[]>`.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was that Im doing a laboratory work, and the teacher gave us an Template and I could not change List<Object>[] into List<Student> or something like that, that was the rule. 

But anyway thank you, now I know!!